# A Fourier Analysis Question related to fourier transform of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ functions

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

$f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n),1\leq p\leq 2$ and $g\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n), g$ is not identically $0$, such that $f*g\equiv 0.$ Prove that $f(x)=0$ for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

My strategy is to use that we have $\hat{f}\cdot \hat{g}\equiv 0.$ Now for $n=1$, I know that $\hat{g}$ is a restriction to an entire function and hence if $g$ isn't identically $0$, then the zero set of $\hat{g}$ is discrete. [We simply define $\hat{g}(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(t)e^{-2\pi i tz} dt$.] Hence $\hat{f}$ is $0$ almost everywhere and so $f$ is $0$ almost everywhere. But for $n>1$ how do I prove the similar statement?

Comment: You should say $g$ not $\equiv 0.$

Comment: Thanks @zhw. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy would be the same as $\widehat g$ would be holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and its zero set would be of strictly lower dimension and hence of zero measure. Have in mind that the awkward part here is talking about the Fourier transform of $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ as you would have to prove the result in a dense set or use distributions.

Alternatively you could try the following. If you replace $f$ with a Schwartz function using density (here I think that you need the hypothesis on $p$ to use one of young convolution inequalities), you can study $\hat{f}\cdot\hat{g}$ by fixing variables and working with just entire functions on one variable.

Comment: My main concern is how to define $\hat{g}(z_1,\dots,z_n)$, can you please help me with that? Then maybe we can show it's holomorphic in each coordinate.

Comment: Should it be $\hat{g}(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x) e^{-2\pi i x\cdot z}dx$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}^n$? Though it doesn't match with $n=1$ definition.

Comment: I think my last comment is wrong. See then the function $\hat{g}$ doesn't depend on the imaginary part at all. So, that can't be holomorphic. I think it should be $\sum x_iz_i$ instead of $x\cdot z$. Then it matches with the $n=1$ definition as well.

Comment: @Larsson that is correct, but the notation $x \cdot z$ usually means $\sum x_i \overline{z_i}$ (or $\sum \overline{x_i} z_i$) which also works.

Comment: Yeah, actually what I meant in my comment is think of $x_i$ as an element of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and then take the dot product, which won't work of course.

Comment: In any case that's how you define $\widehat g(z)$, to see that it is holomorphic you only need to note that it is in each variable, that reduces the problem to the one dimensional case for a compactty supported integrand $f$.